# What does the "!" in `while ! nc ...; do...; done` mean

Tags: bash, netcat

I am pretty new to bash, and I come across this code.

```
j=0
while ! nc -z "$host" "$port"; do
  j=$((j+1))
  if [ $j -ge 10 ]; then
    echo >&2 "$host:$port not reachable, giving up"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

I cannot understand how the `!` before the `nc` work here. Can anyone help explain that?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, `!` is a **keyword** (thanks to user1934428 for the correction) which performs a NOT operation.

If the command `nc -z "$host" "$port"` didn't performed successfully, it would return "false" (i.e. a non-zero value). Hence, the `! [nc command]` would return "true" (i.e. zero).

So it's like "while this `nc` command fails, do the loop. After ten tries (`$j` is greater than or equal to 10), give up".

You might want to have a peek on this [interactive tutorial](https://www.learnshell.org/) and this [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting).

Comment: Thank you! It is really clear. Also, these two resources are awesome!

Comment: @Amessihel : Minor correction - the `!`  is not an operator, but is considered (by bash and zsh as well) as a shell keyword (similar to `time`). You can see it when doing a `type '!'`.

Comment: @Xinbin, I figured out I wrote a huge typo. Of course if the `nc` command performed succesfully, `! nc` would return false. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Amessihel, thanks for the update! Though it doesn't affect my understanding of the logic, I should for sure learning the true concept... especially for such a newbie like me